# need to pass valid token or set environment variable

Tags: python, knn, training-data

I am a beginner trying to train a KNN image classifier. I tried this code from Jupyter on VSCode but it showed me this error.

```
PS C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\Python> python training.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training.py", line 15, in <module>
    cvstudioClient = cvstudio.CVStudio()
  File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\skillsnetwork\cvstudio.py", line 178, in __init__
    raise Exception('need to pass valid token or set CV_STUDIO_TOKEN environment variable')
Exception: need to pass valid token or set CV_STUDIO_TOKEN environment variable
```

It ran successfully on Jupyter. Here is my Code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from imutils import paths
import seaborn as sns
import random
import time 
from datetime import datetime
import cv2 as cv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import os 
from skillsnetwork import cvstudio

cvstudioClient = cvstudio.CVStudio(__init__)
cvstudioClient.downloadAll()
```

Please help if anyone can.